# Problem with comments_number()

Tags: functions

The following code:

```
echo '<ul>';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    $title = get_the_title();
    echo '<li>' . $title . comments_number() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

moves the comments ABOVE and outside of the `<li>` like this:

```
1 Comment 

Hello world!
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `get_comments_number()` as that doesn't echo the results, while `comments_number` does echo